# How can I change element's style based on the time of day?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, momentjs

I'm trying to make a page that has a calendar for the day that shows each hour of the day from 9AM to 5PM. I want each hour to display a different color based on the time of day (gray if the hour past, green if the hour is in the future, red if it is the current hour). I'm trying to use moment.js to help me with this. Here is what I think was my best attempt:

```js
var checkTime = function () {
    var hour = $(".hour").text().trim();

    var time = moment(hour, "LT");
    console.log(time)

    //remove any old classes from element
    $(".hour").removeClass(".present .past .future");

    // apply new class if task is near/over due date
    if (moment().isAfter(time)) {
        $(".hour").addClass(".past");
    } else if (moment().isBefore(time)) {
        $(".hour").addClass(".future");
    } else {
        $(".hour").addClass(".present");
    }
}

checkTime();
```

And here is an example of one corresponding HTML element:

```html
        <div class="time-block row nine">
          <p class="hour">9:00 AM </p>
          <textarea class="textarea"></textarea>
          <button class="saveBtn col-1"></button>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I got the "time logic" correct (check the if statement), but this should be what you are looking for.

```
var objDate = new Date();
    var hours = objDate.getHours();
    if(hours >= 9 && hours <= 17){
        $(".hour").addClass("present");
    }
    elseif(hours < 9){
        $(".hour").addClass("past");
    }
    else{
        $(".hour").addClass("future");
    }
```

Note that this uses the client's time, so if you're using this on a web page worldwide, then you might be opened in Europe but at the same time closed in the US.

Comment: I couldn't quite get this method to work, but thank you. I added my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  function makeHour(dt) {
    return dt.getHours() + (dt.getMinutes() / 60);
  }

  function textToDate(str) {
    var h = parseInt(str.slice(0, str.indexOf(":")));
    var m = parseInt(str.slice(str.indexOf(":") + 1, -2));
    var mer = str.slice(-2);
    if (mer == "PM") {
      h = h + 12;
    }
    var dt = new Date();
    dt.setHours(h, m);
    return dt;
  }

  function compHours(a, b) {
    var r = 0;
    if (a < b) {
      r = -1;
    }
    if (a > b) {
      r = 1;
    }
    return r;
  }

  function checkTime() {
    var then = textToDate($(".hour").text().trim());
    var now = new Date();
    var thenH = makeHour(then);
    var nowH = makeHour(now);
    console.log(then, now);
    var test = compHours(thenH, nowH);
    console.log(thenH, nowH, test);
    if (test == 0) {
      $(".hour").addClass("present");
    } else if (test == -1) {
      $(".hour").addClass("past");
    } else {
      $(".hour").addClass("future");
    }
  }

  checkTime();
});
```

```css
.past {
  background-color: gray;
}

.present {
  background-color: red;
}

.future {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="time-block row nine">
  <p class="hour">9:15 AM </p>
  <textarea class="textarea"></textarea>
  <button class="saveBtn col-1">BTN</button>
</div>
```

It's best to convert the Hours and Minutes into an Integer. This way you can easily compare the hours. I use `-1`, `0`, and `1` for Past, Present, and Future.

Comment: I couldn't quite get this method to work, but thank you. I added my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I got it to work (Keep in mind, I had to change some classes/id's in HTML and then selectors in JS):

```js
//Change textarea background color based on time
var checkTime = function () {

    //Get Current time
    var currentTime = moment().format('H');

    //get all elements with class "taskarea"
    var timeBlockElements = $(".textarea");

    //loop through taskarea classes
    for (var i = 0 ; i < timeBlockElements.length ; i++) {

        //Get element i's ID as a string
        var elementID = timeBlockElements[i].id;

        //get element by ID
        var manipID = document.getElementById(timeBlockElements[i].id)

        //remove any old classes from element
        $(timeBlockElements[i].id).removeClass(".present .past .future");

        // apply new class if task is present/past/future
        if (elementID < currentTime) {
            $(manipID).addClass("past");
        } else if (elementID > currentTime) {
            $(manipID).addClass("future");
        } else {
            $(manipID).addClass("present");
        }
    }
}

// checkTime every 5 minutes
setInterval(checkTime(), (1000 * 60) * 5);
```

And the HTML:

```html
        <div class="time-block row nine">
          <p class="hour col-1">9:00 AM </p>
          <textarea class="textarea col-10" id="09"></textarea>
          <button class="saveBtn col-1"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/metro/26/000000/save.png"/></button>
        </div>
```